# Makefile function that processes one input variable, and checks the result is not empty, and errors out on failure

Tags: makefile

I want to create a function in a makefile that can be called to process a variable but also check the result of that process and exit out of the make if it is bad.  Specifically, I am converting the input variable from hex to decimal using "bc" but if the input has lower case letters, the result from bc is empty.  Therefore I want to do the conversion and check the result.  I want make to stop with an error if it is blank. Also, I may want to ensure the input is not blank to start.

It seems makefile functions aren't designed like code that can return a value or pass by reference and they are more like a macro.  Is there a way to do this?  I might have given up and just called bash or some other scripting language from make but I'd rather not check the return value each time because it has to be done many places.  If I can "exit" from the makefile function, that would be great.

This is pseudocode only, no need to point out syntax errors.

```
MyVariable := 1A2B3C4D
MyVariable := $(call MyFunc, MyVariable)

# I don't know how to define a multiline function that returns a value
MyFunc =

# Make sure it is not empty and quit if it is
ifeq ($(strip $(0)),)
    echo "Variable should not be empty!"
    exit(-1)
endif

# Convert from hex to decimal. Force uppercase except the word ibase. 
OutPut = $(shell echo "ibase=16; $(strip $(0))" | tr a-z A-Z | sed 's/IBASE/ibase/g' | bc) 

# Then somehow return a value?!
return (OutPut)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you provide sample input, expected output. Also, you refer to "makefile functions" - what have you tried to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles aren't procedural languages.  They don't have "return values".  But, there are functions and one of them is [`error`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html) which will cause make to exit with an error message.  There is also an [`if` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html).  In makefiles, conditions are considered true if they are not empty, and false if they are empty.  So something like this should work:

```
OutPut = $(shell echo "ibase=16; $(strip $(0))" | tr a-z A-Z | sed 's/IBASE/ibase/g' | bc) 

$(if $(OutPut),,$(error Empty output))
```